# Using graphicx and Gin to set figure width, only for a single image (what is the default width of a figure, or clearing the global width)

Tags: graphics

I would like to control multiple sub figures width in a single figure, and then set them to the default afterwards, MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}~%
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{This figure should be of normal width \label{fig}}
\end{figure}


\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}~%
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{This figure should be wider than in figure \ref{fig}}
\end{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{} %What should I write here to free the width????

\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}~%
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{This figure should be of normal width, like figure \ref{fig}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The above produces:
[image]

Comment: Great picture selection!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is to put the Gin setting inside the figure, then it will be reset at the end of the group. But beside this: The default value is `!`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}~%
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{This figure should be of normal width \label{fig}}
\end{figure}


\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}

    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}~%
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{This figure should be wider than in figure \ref{fig}}
\end{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=!} %What should I write here to free the width????

\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}~%
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{This figure should be of normal width, like figure \ref{fig}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll accept the answer sometime after the timelimit has expired ;-)