# Usage of image actual size

Tags: graphics, size

The tag `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio} %` was given as global in the `TeX` file, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio} %
\begin{document}
...

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{...eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which scales all the images into some appropriate values, but I should use some of the images with actual size (without scaling and should 100% actual size), how can I achieve? Please advise

Comment: If the actual size is less of usable page dimensions and you dont give specifications for size in \includegraphics command, the image is gived in his actual size.

Comment: I'm using `\includegraphics{...eps}`, but the size of the image was scaled some values due to tag `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}`

Comment: Comment the tag.

Comment: Main problem is I need that tag, and want to switch off for very few figures only

Comment: With this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489740/using-graphicx-and-gin-to-set-figure-width-only-for-a-single-image-what-is-the
You ca try {\setkeys{Gin}{width=!}
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
}

Comment: @pascal974, Yes, it's solved the issue, thanks a lot